# Setting Cloud Monitoring uptime checks for non publicly accessible backends

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-monitoring

I'm having some trouble setting uptime checks for some Cloud Run services that don't allow unauthenticated invocations.

For context, I'm using Cloud Endpoints + ESPv2 as an API gateway that's connected to a few Cloud Run services.

The ESPv2 container/API gateway allows unauthenticated invocations, but the underlying Cloud Run services do not (since requests to these backends flow via the API gateway).

Each Cloud Run service has an internal health check endpoint that I'd like to hit periodically via Cloud Monitoring uptime checks.

This serves the purpose of ensuring that my Cloud Run services are healthy, but also gives the added benefit of reduced cold boot times as the containers are kept 'warm'

However, since the protected Cloud Run services expect a valid authorisation header all of the requests from Cloud Monitoring fail with a 403.

From the Cloud Monitoring UI, it looks like you can only configure a static auth header, which won't work in this case. I need to be able to dynamically create an auth header per request sent from Cloud Monitoring.

I can see that Cloud Scheduler supports this already. I have a few internal endpoints on the Cloud Run services (that aren't exposed via the API gateway) that are hit via Cloud Scheduler, and I am able to configure an OIDC auth header on each request. Ideally, I'd be able to do the same with Cloud Monitoring.

I can see a few workarounds for this, but all of them are less than ideal:

- Allow unauthenticated invocations for the underlying Cloud Run services. This will make my internal services publicly accessible and then I will have to worry about handling auth within each service.
- Expose the internal endpoints via the API gateway/ESPv2. This is effectively the same as the previous workaround.
- Expose the internal endpoints via the API gateway/ESPv2 AND configure some sort of auth. This sort of works but at the time of writing the only auth methods supported by ESPv2 are API Keys and JWT. JWT is already out of the question but I guess an API key would work. Again, this requires a bit of set up which I'd rather avoid if possible.

Would appreciate any thought/advice on this.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to get the uptime check of a platform which provision resources and run you app only on demand? There is a no sense here!

Comment: The internal endpoint has a healthcheck built into it which basically checks each of the service’s external dependencies (database, redis etc.), so hitting it via uptime gives an indication that the service is ‘healthy’.

Comment: Also there is the added benefit that I mentioned that the cloud run services are kept ‘warm’

Answer (score -2):

This simple solution may work on your use case as it is easier to just use a TCP uptime check on port 443:

1. Create your own Cloud Run service using https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/prebuilt-deploy.
2. Create a new uptime check on TCP port 443 Cloud Run URL.
3. Wait a couple of minutes.

> Location results: All locations passed
>
> Virginia OK
> Oregon OK
> Iowa OK
> Belgium OK
> Singapore OK
> Sao Paulo OK

I would also like to advise that Cloud Run is a Google fully managed product and it has a [99.95 % monthly up time SLA](https://cloud.google.com/run/sla), with [no recent incidents](https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/cloud-run) in the past few months, but proactively monitoring this on your end is a very good thing too.

Comment: this would not work - even a garbage cloud run URL will return Success on a TCP/443 check. I just tried it.